# Class diagram show classes where the text runs off the box?

Tags: c++, uml, enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect(using EA ver7.5) the class diagram show classes where the text runs off the box?

How can I keep this from happening?  Otherthing to note:  this occurs on File->Print Preview and when printing.  It is otherwise resolved ok.

[image]

2nd image:
From RA... I Did the (Cntrl A) and then `Elements->Appearance->Autosize`.

Also did multiple `Diagram->Layout Diagram`.

[image]

Comment: Is this from auto generated diagrams of reverse engineered code? Maybe you'll need to follow the 2nd instruction from RA's answer to resize the elements to fit after importing. A re-layout would be necessary also after doing this.

Comment: Yes, this is a second project.  The first project had no problems drawing.  I don't know why there are problems.

Comment: @jdl I've also noticed that behavior several times when reverse engineering from code. That might also happen if you drag elements into a diagram from the project browser, but usually the elements will be resized as soon you deselect them. I don't know if there was already a bug report made to Sparx about this issue, would be worth one. You may search the user forum if someone else stumbled over this, but make a bug report using the official site if you want.

Comment: @DeadMG No UML usually doesn't, what can give you a PITA is the tools trying to get it right (which isn't simple of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resize a single box, refer to the following:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_fundamentals/resizeelements.html

If you want to automatically resize all the elements in the diagram, use these instructions:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_fundamentals/autosizeelements.html

Comment: Did the (Cntrl A) and then Elements->Appearance->Autosize.  Also did multiple Diagram->Layout Diagram and still get the 2nd image??

Comment: @jdl Strange.  I think you may have run into a bug.  You can also try the automatic diagram layout mechanism (http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_fundamentals/layoutadiagram.html) to see if you have better luck.  Otherwise, a bug report might be in order.

Comment: Otherthing to note: this occurs on File->Print Preview and when printing. It is otherwise resolved ok